# drawStaticText gives error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I trying to draw static text but getting error, can you explain what I doing wrong, why NoneType?

here is the code:

```
sT = QtGui.QStaticText()
text = 'text'
painter.drawStaticText(QtCore.QPoint(40, 50), sT.setText(text))
```

and error:

```
painter.drawStaticText(QtCore.QPoint(40, 50), staticT.setText(text))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QPainter.drawStaticText(QPointF, QStaticText): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
QPainter.drawStaticText(QPoint, QStaticText): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
QPainter.drawStaticText(int, int, QStaticText): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPoint'
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to do in two steps - first `sT.setText(text)` and later `drawStaticText(QtCore.QPoint(40, 50), sT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do in two steps

```
sT.setText(text)
painter.drawStaticText(QtCore.QPoint(40, 50), sT)
```

because `sT.setText(text)` returns `None`, not `QStaticText` object.